# Qt, how to remove the frame of widget

Tags: qt

I realize two QPlainTextEdit and lay them in one QSplitter, but the margin  of these two widgets is a bit large. I also notice the wigets of Qt creator is very compact. I don't know how to reduce the distance of my widgets.
[image]
[image]

I post my code below:

```
QVBoxLayout * spuvbox = new QVBoxLayout ;
SPUEdit = new CodeEditor;
QLabel *label1 = new QLabel("SPU Code");
spuvbox->addWidget(label1);
spuvbox->addWidget(SPUEdit);
QWidget    * spuwidget = new QWidget;
spuwidget->setLayout(spuvbox);

QVBoxLayout * mpuvbox = new QVBoxLayout ;
MPUEdit = new CodeEditor;
QLabel *label2 = new QLabel("MPU Code");
mpuvbox->addWidget(label2);
mpuvbox->addWidget(MPUEdit);
QWidget    * mpuwidget = new QWidget;
mpuwidget->setLayout(mpuvbox);

QSplitter * textsplitter = new QSplitter(Qt::Horizontal,0);
textsplitter->setHandleWidth(2);
textsplitter->addWidget(spuwidget);
textsplitter->addWidget(mpuwidget);
setCentralWidget(textsplitter);
```

Comment: To reduce the distance between widgets in your layouts you might set the spacing value to zero using `QBoxLayout::setSpacing()` function. For example: `spuvbox->setSpacing(0);`.

Comment: It helps to reduce the margin between the label and the CodeEditor. But the margin between spubox and mpubox is still large

Comment: Well, than play with `QWidget::setContentsMargins()` of related widgets. Like: `SPUEdit->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);` or so.

Comment: thanks, it works when I use: spuvbox->setContentsMargins